# multi captures comparision opencv2.3.0 python2.7 windows

Tags: python, opencv, frame, capture

I'm trying to have my webcam do the following:

1. capture 10 captures for 1 minute duration (one capture every 6
   seconds).
2. Then save them into an array or on the computer.
3. Then get other captures for 5 minutes duration (one capture every 6
   seconds) and compare each capture with the first array.

so far I have this code:

```
import cv

cv.NamedWindow("Camera", 1)
# in case im using another camera:
cv.NamedWindow("Camera", 2)

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)

while True:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.ShowImage("Camera", img)
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
        break

cv.DestroyWindow("Camera")
```

How do I proceed with this? any ideas?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"?

Comment: pictures will be taken for computer users' upper part of their body (head, shoulders, elbow etc). So I want to compare the current captures (5 minutes duration) to the saved captures (1 minute duration) based on the upper body position and posture. if they match, pass. if not fail.
Hope that helped.

Comment: I just wana know how to make the webcam(s) take pics and save them by itself? not by the user prompt.